# How do I read a position of a list of lines in text file

Tags: java, arrays, file, text

I am building a freight management system. I want to list out the intermediate ports available between the source and destination after the user has input the source port and destination port. But I don't know how to do that. I saved the port name and distance of each port in the text file where one line for each port. The location variable is used to calculate the distance between source and destination. I wanted to use the position variable to locate the ports in between the source and destination.

> Newes;10;
>
> Harrytown;25;
>
> Truy;33;
>
> East Port;47;
>
> Athens;56;
>
> Nasky;71;

```
private int location, location1, position, position1;
private String source, destination;    

public void choosePort(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter the source.");
    source = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the destination.");
    destination = sc.nextLine();
    try{
        File f = new File("Port.txt");
        Scanner file = new Scanner(f);
        
        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            String line = file.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split(";");
            if(split[0].equals(source)){
                location = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                position = i;
            }
            else if(split[0].equals(destination)){
                location1 = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
                position1 = i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Please paste the source code as text inside your question, not as an image. Also what isn't working with your current code ?

Comment: Are all of the ports on the same geometric line?

Comment: no, they are in separate line.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want ports displayed between source and destination. For example, if a user selects 'Newes" as a starting point and 'Trury' as a destination, you would like 'Harrytown' displayed as an intermediate. There are several ways you can do this. The easiest way, I believe is to use a second scanner to scan word for word, a delimiter, and a print statement inside that while loop.

```
while(file.hasNextLine())
{
 String line = file.nextLine();
 Scanner sff = new Scanner(line);
 sff.useDelimiter(";"); // scanner will see ';' and skip over it
 String temp1 = sff.next;
 if ( source.equals(temp1))
 {
 System.out.println(file.nextLine());
 }
```

After this, just complete out the code. write another `file.nextLine()` to see if it matches destination, if it does not, print out the line. When `sff` matches the destination, print out that final line then insert a `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

something quick like.

```
    boolean isPrint = false;
    while(file.hasNextLine()){
        String line = file.nextLine();
        String[] split = line.split(";");
        if(split[0].equals(destination)){
           isPrint = false;
        }
        if (isPrint) { System.out.println(split[1]);}
        if(split[0].equals(source)){
             print = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation but I want the name of the intermediate ports to be displayed after the user enter the input of source and destination.

Comment: changed it accordingly